# mkisofs is not including tar.gz file in custom iso

Tags: centos, kickstart, mkisofs

I am customizing centos iso, i took standard CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810.iso and extract it and custom folder and add my files.

Now i am recreating custom iso with below command

```
mkisofs -o centos-7-custom1.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -V 'CentOS 7 x86_64' -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T isolinux/
```

its adding all files but not including one file(tar.gz) which has size of 3GB and no error.

in output no error and strange is that from one folder it including all files except this big size file.

is there any restriction?

PS: i am running this command from mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Native* **iso9660** doesn't support files over **2GB**. You need to use **iso9660:1988** instead by adding `-level 3` option to you command.

[man 8 mkisofs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs):

> -iso-level level
>
> . . .
>
> With level 3, no restrictions (other than ISO-9660:1988) do apply
>
> . . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you did use a recent original version of `mkisofs` instead of the broken modified variant you get on Centos, you did get the following warning message:

```
 mkisofs: Value too large for defined data type. File xxx.tar-gz is too large for current mkisofs settings (-iso-level 3 or more required) - ignoring
```

So your problem was to not to use a user friendly Linux distro. The message mentioned above has been added in February 2008 already.

Comment: Anyway: If the mentioned error message was missing, then the used mkisofs version is outdated since more than 11 years.